# Is there a need for a LB in preference for the built-in policies in Cassandra C# driver?

Tags: database, performance, cassandra, load-balancing, datastax

I have a Ldap server that gives to each of my api instance access keys and endpoints. I need to be flexible, the goal is tho be able to change the database cluster without downtime.

My first idea was to put a LB in front of the cassandra cluster but I guess I will lose the optimization that the driver will do (it's guessing I don't really know I'm new to Cassandra) so I just give one ContactPoint when I launch the API that correspond to LB endpoint. When I need to improve throughput I just pop extra nodes behind the LB and it manage congestion through constant health-checking. It can add latency but with my internal DNS I can change the endpoint IP (I don't know who often the driver will perform a DNS query or if if will do it when ContactPoint is unavailable) and keep services on track if the LB crash or whatever.

Now if it kills performances I can add all my Cassandra nodes to the ContactPoints and let the driver do his magic. The problem is that I will need to change the ContactPoints each and every time I change the Cassandra cluster, and I don't know if I can do that without restarting my Api services which means manual intervention to all my Api instances. Maybe I can change them and the singleton add some rw mutex block all reader change the list, reconnect to every nodes and give readers the access back. Maybe but I don't think so ... I rather prefer to use the LB but if they're some Cassandra expert or Datastax devs here !

Is there a need for a LB in preference for the built-in policies in Cassandra C# driver?

Answer (score 1):

The use of hardware or software load-balancers and/or virtual IPs (VIPs) is not recommended.

As you already stated, the Cassandra drivers use a built-in load-balancing policy and is aware of the cluster topology plus the health of the nodes. When you place a load-balancer or VIP in front of the cluster, the driver loses the ability to intelligently route requests.

For example if you are using the Java driver, by default the driver uses a load-balancing policy that routes queries to the local data centre with a token-aware policy that prefers to route requests to replicas (nodes) that own the data being queried.

The driver knows about the nodes in the cluster because it connects to contact points (a list of node IP addresses) to establish a control connection at startup time. The driver uses the control connection to perform tasks that include querying the system tables to learn about the cluster topology. Using the control connection, the driver also listens for changes to the cluster automatically so it is aware of things like node additions, node outages, new data centres and decommissions in real time.

For these reasons, it is not advisable to use external load balancers or DNS virtual IPs since it affects the ability of the drivers to operate in the optimum way.

If you're interested, check out the Java driver documentation on [Control connection](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/manual/core/control_connection/) and [Load balancing](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/manual/core/load_balancing/). Cheers!

Comment: Thank you very much for your time ! Ok I just need to define a sort of "master" node that I will use as the entrypoint for the cluster when I do Cassandra.Builder then it will optain the topography. Is there any difference in therms of support between the .net core driver and the java one (spring boot, micronaut ... I guess) ?

Comment: FWIW the use of "master" or "primary/secondary" doesn't apply to C* -- all nodes are the same with no single point of failure. Most developers use the same nodes in the seeds list for contact points -- pick at least 2 nodes in the local DC. And no, the C# driver works in the same manner. Cheers!